# Mysql query to provide totalsum and subquery sum in same output

Tags: mysql

How do I create a query that provides total sums in one column, and subtotals dependent on a query in another?

Given the following table

```
mysql> +------+------+------+--------+
-> | A    | B    | num  | status |
-> +------+------+------+--------+
-> | e    | f    |   34 | Y      |
-> | e    | f    |   45 | Y      |
-> | g    | h    |   22 | N      |
-> | a    | f    |   55 | Y      |
-> | d    | g    |   66 | N      |
-> | e    | f    |   67 | Y      |
-> | a    | f    |   88 | Y      |
-> | e    | g    |   36 | N      |
-> | d    | g    |   44 | N      |
-> | a    | h    |   33 | Y      |
-> | a    | g    |   33 | N      |
-> | e    | x    |  343 | Y      |
-> | a    | a    |   33 | N      |
-> +------+------+------+--------+
-> 13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would like to output a table that shows: grouped by A; the total sum of num and the total sum of num where status = Y.

This:

```
select A, sum(num),
       (select sum(num) from  test where ( status = 'Y')) 
from test 
group by A;

mysql> +------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
-> | A    | sum(num) | (select sum(num) from  test where ( status = 'Y')) |
-> +------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
-> | a    |      242 |                                                665 |
-> | d    |      110 |                                                665 |
-> | e    |      525 |                                                665 |
-> | g    |       22 |                                                665 |
-> +------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

...provides the wrong result, off course. It gives the total sum of all A in column 3.

I would have liked:

```
mysql> +------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
-> | A    | sum(num) | (select sum(num) from  test where ( status = 'Y')) |
-> +------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
-> | a    |      242 |                                                176 |
-> | d    |      110 |                                                  0 |
-> | e    |      525 |                                                489 |
-> | g    |       22 |                                                  0 |
-> +------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

br
AK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    `A`,
    SUM(`num`) as `sum_num`,
    SUM(IF(`status` = 'Y',`num`,0)) as `sum_status_yes`
FROM `test`
GROUP BY `A`
ORDER BY `A`;
```

You can also use this technique to get counts, averages, etc.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please accept the answer - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select a, sum(num),
       sum(case when status = 'Y' then num else 0 end)
from t
group by a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A, SUM(num), SUM( IF( status='Y', num, 0 ) ) 
FROM test 
GROUP BY A
```